# Как создать ссылку без AJAX?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, link

У меня есть сайт на Wordpress (тема Elision). Здесь хедер и футер статичный, а место между ними перезагружается без перезагрузки всей страницы.

Я хочу, чтобы ссылка на главную страницу была без AJAX и полностью перезагружала страницу, так как моя главная страница должна быть без хедера и футера.

Answer (score 0):

Elision - обычная тема на основе Visual Composer с расширениями от QODE. Страница выводится через php без всякого ajax. ajax используется при переходах между страницами. Видимо, вопрос в этом.

В настройках темы есть переключатель AJAX Animations ON/OFF, выключите его.

Comment: Так то работает, но тогда плавные переходы пропадут...)) Или это лучшее решение?)

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю вопроса. Покажите конкретную страницу и конкретный элемент, который обновляется через ajax.

Comment: Вот эта тема. http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/elision/
Хочу, чтобы при нажатии пункт меню "Home" открывалась главная с полной перезагрузкой страницы.

Comment: Похоже, только Page Transitions Off позволяет переключать страницы без ajax. Но я никак не могу понять - а чем мешает наличие ajax перезагрузки? Не хотите `header` и `footer` - поставьте им `display: none;` и дело с концом. И пусть ajax туда пишет что хочет.

Comment: Я хочу главную страницу - слайдер на весь экран с кнопкой "Войти" без хедера и футера. Я даже в header.php и footer.php поставил отображать хедер и футер везде кроме главной. Но когда я нажимаю "Войти", открывается сайт с хедером и футером (так и должно быть). Но когда я нажимаю в меню "Главная" меня перекидает на главную страницу со слайдером, но хедер и футер не исчезает.... ))

Comment: Без кода помочь нельзя. Здесь не телепаты.